# Inclusion of dshow.h results in definition errors

Tags: c++, directshow

I am trying to do a few things using DirectShow for audio playback. I have a header file, at the top is:

```
#pragma once
#include <dshow.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")
```

and then it goes on to define a class.
When including dshow.h I get the following complilation errors:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\ddraw.h(703) : error C2011: '_DDPIXELFORMAT' : 'struct' type redefinition
>
> c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\include\ksmedia.h(5749) : see declaration of '_DDPIXELFORMAT'
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\ddraw.h(2249) : error C2079: '_DDSURFACEDESC::ddpfPixelFormat' uses undefined struct '_DDPIXELFORMAT'
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\ddraw.h(2292) : error C2079: '_DDSURFACEDESC2::ddpfPixelFormat' uses undefined struct '_DDPIXELFORMAT'
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\strmif.h(12918) : error C2011: 'tagTIMECODE_SAMPLE' : 'struct' type redefinition
>
> c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\include\ksmedia.h(5274) : see declaration of 'tagTIMECODE_SAMPLE'

I can't figure out what would cause these errors in this case. The header file is part of an MFC project if that makes any difference. Any advice?

Comment: Where does your `dshow.h` come from? The same SDK, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by changing the order of the #include definitions. I moved the header file that the above code was defined in to the top and it works ok now. Must have been a clash with some code in another file, possibly some directSound related stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this SDK integration error a couple times, most recently when integrating a win32 console app with a library that uses Windows CoreAudio and the error occurred with a stdafx.h:

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT        // Allow use of features specific to Windows XP or later.                   
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502 // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.
#endif                      

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>



// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
#include <afx.h>
#include <afxwin.h>
```

Then to resolve the error, I added the following below the current includes:

```
#include <winioctl.h>
#if (MSC_VER < 1400)
#include <strmif.h>
#endif
```

Hopefully this will help someone in the future facing this issue.
EB